# how to copy the include folder to the bin folder with post compile event?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to copy all my include folder on the post compile event to the bin folder. i wrote this command

```
  XCOPY ".\include\*.*" "..\bin\include" /S /Y
```

but i get error MSB3073 (error MSB3073 )
the command VCEnd existed with code 1

I also try to do it with 'copy' and without /S /Y but nothing work

What i did wrong ? 
How to do it ?

Comment: Always remember to search for your error messages first. The likelihood of finding others with the problem and who have had them solved one way or another is ever increasing. If nothing else you should be able to find out what the error means and possibly be able to figure out the problem and its solution yourself.

Comment: the answer attached does not solve anything.

Comment: Did you check and try *all* answers? And are you fully certain of the relative paths you use? Are you sure that the "current directory" is what you think it is? And what research have you done about the error itself?